# Strange Behavior with SqlDataReader and long columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I stumbled across this thing today:

I have a little helper method with the following:

```
private static T GetValOrDefault<T>(this IDataRecord rdr, string name)
{
    return rdr[name] is T ? (T) rdr[name] : default(T);
}
```

and all my models use `public long Id { get; set; }`

SQL server columns are `BIGINT`

Somehow the `GetValOrDefault<long>("Id")` returns '0', and i went ahead and used the Immediate Window there, and had a look at `rdr["Id"].GetType()`

It was `Int32`... any ideas why that happens?
Everywhere i look, it says `BIGINT = INT64 = long`... and somehow the SqlDataReader gives me int32...

Edit:
That is my Sql Query:

```
    SELECT
        Id,
        Created,
        CreatedById,
        LastModified,
        LastModifiedById,
        Deleted,
        DeletedById
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE Id = @id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BIGINT column should be returned as a long.  I suspect a bug in your code - perhaps you're not getting the column you think you are, from the database you think you are using, or perhaps your SQL query is casting the column value.

Comment: you were right, i used a temp table with `DECLARE @temp AS TABLE(Id int`

Answer (score 1):

your can use Convert.ChnageType implement

```
public T Change<T>(IDataReader rd,string fieldName)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(rd[fieldName], typeof(T));
}
```